# Removing support for older iOS version

Tags: ios, app-store, version

What exactly happens if you release a version of your app that removes support of an older version of iOS? (e.g. removing iOS 7 support)

1. Will users that already bought the app still be able to download the old version?
2. Will users on that iOS version still be able to discover and install the old version of my app?

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to discover the answer to the question myself. I used an old iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.1 and found an app that used to support iOS 7 but no longer does.

1. Yes, users that bought/installed the app in the past will be able to restore it by using the "Purchased" section from within the "Updates" tab of the "App Store" app.
2. No, users will be able to find the app, but actually won't be able to install it:

   - The app still appears when searching on the app store.
   - The app states "requires iOS 8 or newer".
   - The "Get" button is clickable, but they won't actually be able to install the app. Instead (after they've entered their password) they will be presented with an alert view explaining to them that they'll have to upgrade to iOS 8 (even though this is not actually possible on an iPhone 7)

Comment: Not sure about point 1 you added as an answer. Have you tried it practically ? Because as per my mind, it should give you same result as point 2.

Comment: I just confirmed that behaviour. The account on the afore mentioned iPhone 4 had acquired "Runtastic". When I try to install it via the "Purchased" section I get a dialog stating "Download an older version of this app? The current version requires iOS 8.0 or later, but you can download the last compatible version." with two buttons "Cancel" and "Download".

Comment: However when I try to download "TestFlight" app on that device I don't get an option to download an older version. Since Apple acquired that app and rereleased it they most likely removed all the older versions that included support for iOS 7.